# Track typed words in address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I need to keep track of keys pressed because it's an experiment where typing input is important.
I am using this in order to keep track of all keys pressed

```
function keypress(e)
{
   if (!e) e= event;
   var focused = document.activeElement;
   var a = String.fromCharCode(e.keycode);
}

function init()
{
    if (document.addEventListener)
    {
       document.addEventListener("keypress",keypress,false);
    }
    else if (document.attachEvent)
    {
       document.attachEvent("onkeypress", keypress);
    }
    else
    {
       document.onkeypress= keypress;
    }
}

function suppressdefault(e)
{
       if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
       if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
</script>
```

It works pretty well, however if user writes something at address bar (where the url is written) it doesn't track these characters.

I have been wondering, is there any way to track those keys types there? If not, is there any way to stop user from writing anything at direction bar?

Comment: Got a fiddle link? For we can poke around in?

Comment: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html that's all I used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean this, right?

[image]

That bar isn't part of the web page, and a web page can only listen to keystrokes sent to the web page. So you can't (you shouldn't be able to, anyway) detect or stop those keystrokes.

But you can open a window without an address bar. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

```
window.open('http://www.example.com/', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/fisehihila/1/

In modern desktop browsers, they actually do show the location bar to prevent phishing, but it's not editable.

[image]

Here it is grayed out in Firefox release channel on Windows 7. You can select it, but you can't type in it.

The options to fiddle with these window features have limited support in mobile browsers though.

Comment: Great idea, thank you, gonna accept this unless something better shows up